# Initial value for useState isn't updating when using Virtual Keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-simple-keyboard

Beginner here. Trying to get [react-simple-keyboard](https://github.com/hodgef/react-simple-keyboard) working with Gatsby & React.

I initialise my form with some state (`firstName: "Johnn"`). This should be the initial state. I want the user to be able to modify this name, and save the modified version in state.

I initialise my state here:

```js
 const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
     firstName: "Johnn"
  })
```

When I click on the field and press a button on the virtual keyboard (a letter, say), it deletes the content of the whole field and puts the letter there, instead of adding the letter to whats already in there. Also: Clicking on the field and pressing backspace (on the react-simple-keyboard) does not do anything. Why is this?

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import Keyboard from "react-simple-keyboard"
import "react-simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css"
import Layout from "@components/layout"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { Flex, Box } from "rebass/styled-components"
import Input from "@atoms/Input"

import {
  GlobalDispatchContext,
  GlobalStateContext,
} from "../context/GlobalContextProvider"

function App() {
  const dispatch = useContext(GlobalDispatchContext)
  const state = useContext(GlobalStateContext)

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    firstName: "Johnn",
    // firstName: state.customers[state.currentCustomer].firstName,
  })
  const [layoutName, setLayoutName] = useState("default")
  const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("default")

  const [isShiftPressed, setShiftPressed] = useState(false)
  const [isCaps, setCaps] = useState(false)
  const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false)

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm()
  const keyboard = useRef()

  const onChangeAll = newInputs => {
    /**
     * Here we spread the inputs into a new object
     * If we modify the same object, react will not trigger a re-render
     */
    setInputs({ ...newInputs })
  }

  const handleShift = () => {
    const newLayoutName = layoutName === "default" ? "shift" : "default"
    setLayoutName(newLayoutName)
  }

  const onKeyPress = button => {
    if (isShiftPressed === true && !isCaps) {
      setShiftPressed(false)
      handleShift()
    }
    if (button === "{lock}") {
      setCaps(true)
    }
    if (button === "{shift}" || button === "{lock}") {
      setShiftPressed(true)
      handleShift()
    }
  }

  const onChangeInput = event => {
    const inputVal = event.target.value

    setInputs({
      ...inputs,
      [inputName]: inputVal,
    })

    keyboard.current.setInput(inputVal)
  }

  const getInputValue = inputName => {
    return inputs[inputName] || ""
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Flex flexDirection="column" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Input
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            value={getInputValue("firstName")}
            onFocus={() => {
              setInputName("firstName")
            }}
            placeholder={"First Name"}
            onChange={onChangeInput}
          />
        </form>

        <Keyboard
          keyboardRef={r => (keyboard.current = r)}
          inputName={inputName}
          layoutName={layoutName}
          onChangeAll={onChangeAll}
          onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        />
      </Flex>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: why you have to do this much complicated `value={getInputValue("firstName")}`. you can do simply like that `value={inputs.firstName}.`

Comment: I think that's a leftover from something else I tried out before! Thanks for pointing it out! Any idea why the Keyboard isn't modifying what's in state? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use useEffect hook set the initial keyboard value, and on subsequent changes and also remove `keyboard.current.setInput(inputVal)`.

```
const {firstName} = input;
useEffect(() => {
  keyboard.current.setInput(firstName);
}, [firstName]);
```

This will make sure that the initial and subsequent changes of firstName is set in keyboard instance.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-j3whs?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you for the example. Right now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setInput' of undefined`. I am trying to get it working for multiple fields, so I don't have `useState("John")`, but `useState({firstName: "Johnn",})`. Not sure if this is making things go wrong for me?

Comment: Nope, it should be straight forward, can I see your current code after the change? Go through the code sandbox for better understanding. `const { inputs: firstName } = state` this line is for the firstName extraction.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I am having such a hard time and a deadline, so I really appreciate it. I put my changed file here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pond-y37yd?file=/myfile.js does this work for you? can you see it?

Comment: I also spotted that you need to use `const {firstName} = input;` instead of what you had written previously. just saw the edit. however, `keyboard.current` seems undefined for me, that's the error I am getting.

Comment: could you try getting it to work with multiple fields like I had it in my code, i.e. useState({firstName: "Johnn",}) ? I don't know why I can't get it to work, and why `keyboard.current` is undefined for me.

Comment: Weird, its fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-gareth-r9if3 with multiple fields. Not sure why its different in local vs code sandbox

Comment: I can only see one field in the link? Sure you sent the right link?

Comment: My bad, here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-gareth-r9if3?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Oh it does indeed work there! Might it have to do with gatsby? I am very confused now!

Comment: Probably nothing related to gatsby, you could try initializing keyboard in useEffect